# Solr Error loading class solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am running tomcat6 with Solr 3.6.2 (I need to use this version for software compatibility reasons) and when Solr starts up, I get this error in the logs:

```
Error loading class 'solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType'
```

Which later on in the log is states that it cannot find this class.

I am not sure why this is appearing, but I would like some help in trying to fix it. The error messages says that it is a misconfiguration but I am not sure what configuration would be influencing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType was introduced in Solr 4. You will need to upgrade or remove the class from your schema.xml

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I ended up using Solr 3.6 instead.

Comment: For the record, anyone wanting to use spatial recursive will also need to install http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/ ... we ended up upgrading to Solr4 and using in_radius with bbox

Comment: Does it support CIRCLE geometry?